# How can I find a list of points that satisfy constraints?

Tags: plotting

I understand how to make lists with the Select function and NestList, but these are only for one dimensional lists. Is it possible to make lists of all points that satisfy a constraint? For example, all points `{x,y}` that satisfy `PrimeQ[x*y+1]==True`.

Sorry if this is really amateur, I only recently started Mathematica and I'm trying to teach myself the functions.

Comment: Like `Select[pts, PrimeQ[Apply[Times, #] + 1] &]`?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this.  I will show one with `SparseArray`.

```
matrix = SparseArray[{x_, y_} /; PrimeQ[x y + 1] -> 1, {100, 100}]
```

Now try these:

```
MatrixPlot[matrix]

ArrayRules[matrix]

Keys@Most@ArrayRules[matrix]
```

The last one just gives a list of `{x,y}` pairs.

Comment: `f@x` is just alternative notation for `f[x]`.

Comment: What does the ->1 mean?

Comment: @volcanrb , You might be interested in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users) thread.

Comment: @volcanrb It depends on the context. For this use, look up `SparseArray`.